# How to choose a good restaurant in Switzerland?

Tags: online-resources, switzerland, restaurants, basel

I am making a spontaneous day trip to Basel tomorrow, and there is the problem of choosing a nice restaurant for lunch. I don't want a famous place where you need reservations a month in advance to get a 200 Euro meal, I want something quiet, with atmosphere, and not too crowded. Obviously, we could just walk into the first probable place when we are there and hungry, but this strategy has proved quite unreliable in the past, at least for me (maybe other people have a better "nose" for restaurants?)

So, what are my best information sources? Something generic like typing "restaurants Basel" in Google maps, and sifting through the reviews (which are somewhat patchy for Europe)? Making a Google search and hoping that the scraping sites in the high results have copied something useful from somewhere?

If somebody knows of more specific sources with useful information, I'd like to hear about them. Preferably something which has enough info about Switzerland, not an American/global site which only has two-three touristy items per Swiss city.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[foodguide.ch](http://www.foodguide.ch/home.jsp) looks fairly reasonable to me (ratings seem to agree with my impression). Comments by owners and patrons are in German for Basel, though.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of local source I was interested in.

Answer (score 7):

The adivce I give is valid for other places as well.

You can pick a restaurant among the adresses listed by the famous [Guide Michelin](http://www.viamichelin.co.uk/web/Restaurants). Note that Michelin does not only feature top notch high price restaurants.

You can also have a look at [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g188049-Basel.html), independently or as a complement to the Guide Michelin.

Answer (score 5):

An interesting online resource for "insider tips" in Switzerland is [www.ronorp.ch](http://www.ronorp.ch). This site offers a daily newsletter that sends you the latest information about a chosen city. First it was only available for Zurich, but now it is available for all big Swiss cities and also some foreign cities (e.g. London). The newsletter contains information about events, places to go, and other stuff, people living in this city are currently discussing. Also the message board of ronorp is really useful. There are a lot of helpful users that might give you really good hints. There is also a [Wikipedia site about Ronorp](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Orp) (unfortunately only in German).

Answer (score 5):

For the Greater Zurich Area I'd recommend [Züritipp](http://www.zueritipp.ch/gastro/), a collection of all reviews by Zurich's largest newspaper.

Answer (score 4):

Try [places.google.com](http://places.google.com). If you rate restaurants you have already visited, you will get suggestions. The more restaurants you rate, the better the suggestions are.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the tripadvisor app by looking for restaurants in the nearbies. 
Usually it never misses a shot!